# Call was canceled by the message filter (0x80010002), task scheduler in windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I have scheduled my batch file in task scheduler in windows server 2008. Task terminated automatically in between execution . I checked history of task and found message:

> Task Scheduler terminated "{69903b02-c15a-4c67-97b8-3e7d15a125f6}"  instance of the task.

with Event ID 111.

Last run result showing following message:

> Call was canceled by the message filter (0x80010002)

Please suggest the reason for this and how to avoid this in future ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reentering the password for the account which this task trys to run under.
Also, are the permissions right? Have you tried checking the "run with highest privileges" box?

Comment: Hi Riscie,Thanks. I have rights permission. Task was running fine from last one month . it showed this message first time.I will to execute it with highest privileges. Will it be possible to tell you the reason for this message?

Comment: Hi Riscie, Should I restart my machine ? please advise .

Comment: Hi there. A Restart should not be required.The Task Scheduler will run your sheduled task using an elevated privileges token rather than a normal token which uses (UAC). This option has often solved similar problems for me.